# How to add time events in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wanted to know how can I add time to my events in libgdx. I have a button and when you press it a sprite will appear. I want the sprite to appear for only a short period of time. How can I do this? I used Scene2D to make the sprites as an actor.

I will show you an example in pseudo code.

```
wait time = 5 second;
current time = get time;
if (current time > wait time) {
    // do the following
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's two ways to do this. You can either use something similar to your your pseudo code or you can use a timer.

Manual calculation:

```
private Long lifeTime;
private Long delay = 2000L; //1000 milliseconds per second, so 2 seconds.

public void create () {
    lifeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void render () {
    lifeTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (lifetime > delay) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Using a timer:

```
private float delay = 2; //In seconds this time

//At some point you set the timer
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
}, delay);
```

Read more here: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html